# Por quê minha matriz está se reescrevendo?

Tags: python, matriz

Estou querendo criar uma matriz quadrada de ordem N (N é lido), porém ao entrar no loop, minhas matrizes ficam se reescrevendo e assumindo sempre o último número que digitei.

Já tentei alterar o range, trabalhar com indexadores, mas não obtive êxito.

```py
ordem_matriz = int(input("Digite a ordem da matriz (max 10): "))

matriz = [[0] * ordem_matriz] * ordem_matriz

for i in range(len(matriz)):
    for j in range(len(matriz)):
        matriz[i][j] = int(input(f"Digite o vetor [{i}][{j}]: "))
        print(matriz) # isto aqui é só para o controle do que está acontecendo
```

Eu esperava que ele fosse preenchendo cada matriz, um por um, mas ele assume, neste caso, nas 3 matrizes, o valor que digitei. No fim eles acabam se reescrevendo. Como perceptível no 1 de tornando 4 na última linha.

```
Digite a ordem da matriz (max 10): 3

Digite o vetor [0][0]: 1
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]

Digite o vetor [0][1]: 2
[[1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]]

Digite o vetor [0][2]: 3
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

Digite o vetor [1][0]: 4
[[4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Me parece aqui que, por algum motivo, o seu vetor de vetores tem como elementos referências ao mesmo vetor. Não sei explicar o motivo de ter tido este resultado (não entendo de multiplicações de vetores por escalares em Python), mas a alteração em um elemento de um vetor é "sentido" pelos "outros" vetores. Se todos os vetores de linha apontarem para o mesmo objeto, o comportamento é exatamente este que está sendo demonstrado.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado É exatamente isso.

Comment: @Woss, já ia entrar em contato contigo para que eu possa entender o porquê de estar acontecendo isso, mas você foi mais rápido

Comment: Não entendo o porquê, ainda. Sendo que `matriz[i][j]` não estariam toda vez apontando para um vetor `[0]` diferente?

Comment: @AlecsanderCamilo Não parece estar, mas está. Quando você faz algo como `[[0] * 3]*2` você está criando uma lista com três zeros e repetindo essa mesma lista duas vezes. Acessar, então, `matriz[0][0]` ou `matriz[1][0]` será o mesmo elemento. Expliquei melhor na pergunta que citei.